# Is there an RSS aggregation application that supports smartphones?

Tags: rss, google-workspace, feed, aggregation

I'm currently trying to find an alternative to the google reader **service**. I have tried three **server** applications: Rnews, Lilina and Managing News. None of these could be conveniently used on smartphones. Is there a better alternative?

The following is Rnews, Lilina and Managing news rendered on an iphone. None of these are suited for mobile screens.

[image: Rnews rendered on iphone]

[image: Lilina rendered on iphone]

[image: Managing news rendered on iphone]

Comment: This used to be a question on *[serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)*. I think I was misunderstood, but I have added some more emphasis that this is about server applications.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're trying to get away from Google Reader, but I use NewsRob on my Android to access my Google Reader list.  It works great.